# Messed up my site's CSS

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

Well, I did something pretty stupid. I'm using ruby on rails, and I was adding glyphicons to my site , but for some reason they weren't loading properly. A plus sign in my header looked small, and the edit and delete signs on another page came up as rectangles (The browser I was using was Chrome, and all of this was looked at via LocalHost:3000).
I decided to copy and paste the `bootstrap_and_customization.css.scss` file from a git-hub page into my own respective file, just to experiment.

I didn't see much of a difference, aside from spacing. After saving, I found that my website looked completely different. All the CSS and Bootstrap elements seem to be gone. I clicked undo, saved again, and found that my website still looks bizarre.
I'm using gems, which has been pretty easy so far, but right now I'm stumped. I even did `git reset --hard`, so I know all of my code is as it was before I screwed things up.

Could you please help me?

Comment: Have you cleared your browser cache?  Without seeing any of the code involved it's going to be pretty hard for anybody to provide specific help.

Comment: Is this a production environment? Have you tried clearing the asset pipeline? http://stackoverflow.com/a/12291084/300836

Comment: As stupid as it sounds, I don't want to push my code to github, even thought it should be the same since I git reset. THe remote code is https://github.com/thefoodie

Comment: and it's not the production environment, unfortunately. I went and tried that, but thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have something that is compiling the *.SCSS files into *.CSS? If not then they won't do anything.

Comment: how would I do that? the file that I was messing with is  app / assets / stylesheets / bootstrap_and_customization.css.scss 
 file. https://github.com/thefoodie

Comment: Well it probably isn't that file thats causing your problems then, because it sounds like you change anything there if you never compiled the new file to CSS.  Here's how you would do it though http://sass-lang.com/install