# Rails 3.2 continues to serve OLD version of JavaScript asset file - Development Env

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, asset-pipeline

I have a Rails 3.2 application, and in it I have a Javascript file (app.'s) which appears to be 'stuck' at a particular, past, version.  I've updated the file many times, changing its contents significantly, and being sure each time to Save the file - to no effect.  I've rebooted the machine multiple times (thinking at least THAT should clear out the cobwebs) all to no avail.  I'm at my wits end trying to think of ways to un-stick this.

I can see that the file *is* being served, each time I visit the page:

Started GET "/dev-assets/app.js?body=1" for 172.16.0.12 at 2014-04-24 16:49:36 -0700
Served asset /app.js - 200 OK (1ms)

And then later in the same test run (not modified - as I expect):

Started GET "/dev-assets/app.js?body=1" for 172.16.0.10 at 2014-04-24 16:51:31 -0700
Served asset /app.js - 304 Not Modified (0ms)

But *STILL* it has the old contents (which, have a call to 'location.assign' which has since been removed - so the behavior should be significantly different than what I'm seeing.

I have these settings in my development.rb file (but this is not the complete file):

```
config.cache_classes = false

# Log error messages when you accidentally call methods on nil.
config.whiny_nils = true

# Show full error reports and disable caching
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
config.action_controller.perform_caching = false

# From Rails issue 10091 - attemp to keep from loading scripts
# multiple times
config.assets.prefix = "/dev-assets"

# Do not compress assets
config.assets.compress = false

# Expands the lines which load the assets
config.assets.debug = true

# Workaround documented in Rails issue 4145
config.serve_static_assets = false
```

Anyone have any idea how I can clear this old file?

Note - this is very similar to:

[Clear the cache from the Rails asset pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10004365/clear-the-cache-from-the-rails-asset-pipeline)

But none of those suggestions have helped me.

Comment: Did you run assets:precompile? It generates static assets under /public/dev-assets directory. You need to remove /public/dev-assets to generate js dynamically.

Comment: Yes, I do (for Staging & Production).  And I always run rake assets:clean first.  In fact, when this started, I just ran rake assets:clean to eliminate as a possibility in Development.

Comment: Did you check if /public/dev-assets directory in development environment is really empty?

Comment: Yes, there is no public/assets nor public/dev-assets directory present.

Answer (score 0):

This *isn't* a Rails problem.  Rails is serving up the correct file, as verified by by fetching the file in the browser:

```
http://localhost:3000/dev-assets/app.js
```